# Jquery JSON quotes in parameter value

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery

Good day, i have following string as responce:

```
var retstr = {"d":"{\"param1\": \"normal text (\"quoted text\") normal text\",\"param2\": \"4\"}"};
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(retstr.d);
```

This "d" parameter is made by MS for security reasons, and all real json string is passed as value of this parameter. More info [here](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/).

So, params are allready escaped by \" symbol, and when i meet quotes in parameter value it fails to parse. However i can't replace double quotes.

I'm stuck in this and can't solve situation.

Comment: I'm certain you don't have what you've quoted -- at least, you didn't get that from ASP.Net. My guess is you've tried to simplify it for your question (good impulse!) but overdone it. If you show what you're *actually* working with (debugger screenshot, perhaps), we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you've quoted, you'd do this:

```
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(retstr.d);
// Then use `jsonObj.param1` and such
```

...because what you've called `retstr` isn't a string, it's an object that has a property, `d`, which is a string (containing JSON).

But I'm not at all sure what you've quoted is really what you have.

Comment: @ailmcm: I guarantee you that you don't have what you've quoted. At least, you didn't get that from ASP.Net. If you show what you're *actually* working with, we may be able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to parse any thing just loop through json result.

```
var retstr = {"d":"{\"param1\": \"normal text (\"quoted text\") normal text\",\"param2\": \"4\"}"};
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(retstr);
```

and get the element `jsonObj.param1`
or check for `jsonObj.d.param1`

### Edit 1

If you have jquery like below

```
$.ajax({
     contentType: "application/json",
     url: 'http://localhost:16329/Hello',
     dataType: "json"
});
```

Then you don't need to parse it.

Comment: `retstr` isn't a string, you can't use `JSON.parse` on it (and `JSON.parse` is what `$.parseJSON` does).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the response which he is getting is `JSON` but he may have set in jquery to `text/string` which I guessed so I used used the .parse method.